# Save png data to file in C#

Tags: c#, image, png

I am getting png data from hardware and this data I am receiving it as a `String` in C#.

```
tekVISA.Write("SAVe:IMAGe FILEF PNG");
tekVISA.Write("SAVe:IMAGe INKSAVER ON");
tekVISA.Write("HARDCOPY START");
bool status4 = tekVISA.Read(out response);
```

Here `response` receives the data and is of type String. The data I get is as follows:

```
?PNG   IHDR        Oe?¢    IDATx^íY1rôJs_ñ7Pà%h¼^? %?pd8¼ Ac"A¡"A+0àD8 -A¡_xY÷-«_ü83?Aæ?¿??93YOUÿO|g.ï?òAañxç?  ?AI9_Ye?A?ÿó/E?W?3 ^C Qk?ó?Aßüo_ÆaíHrKà?¿yño,n92_CA¡½?O?1N7k(>)?é?iúëB3ñE1IlÜdAò]?OñG?n>?dò83??<[é}NA¡y9A?°pºégü£Öç%?)ëGA'¬ÄV?5Mâ?3XG?._E2?î±ò*A8ºAx?Aºáiúo¿???é-·+1XoM0X?p-Eòq?ÇºD??<??£û?_N7á?V:?AI,f?·ká£½W¼^1r?TOI%{371½üò0XGid>?dæ8_??Y?q19ºa»É`I>E?^}IºOyùU/?,¬c[Z°SS?ôEón5XOOX?¿Å`%?-o(?ia<½jåRVZ½LIÑIIÖO]oIE?D_c°_:ªM_?u%ì?w~¼¬5Ä`wO?g°?R0à_~ùáQ?A¿ü'?Ñ3¿_I"zuÖ!ûäOOIO3íIH½óè·|?o^c?+X?ÖUE?_?/?o^ñæïZ9O?_¥x?lgßm÷U÷/:ÅÑ}?pÖ!?²Æ`I.>M-OA7'f?mòI&úO?¿gV\A:J;[dQ$OÆa°OJ3:1G÷!?_¬ß¬Zsvvk?.Ç¬?k?k$\_æû?ò_g3e°?RD|É'q¬'O?NIÑáÇOIaUùí÷O7#C_Wj?AzåéWàwÉ}ú!£+Xï?EäOIÖ|2dó?c°Ig?dEG÷!Bì3X3_ú¬ôd?$\3E&?oô[íO?1|?µà?»"oo¥5pë(ùlAG?L?AJ+IèÄY?_d°ârT?IOo_9$á?AV?>3P}EIoMÇ»xoO.ÖQ??ÿ?ÆQ$OÆa°OJ341?öQx?n?"ùQ?G·ôx?dOxâ___Qfå>OñGo?]o(?ia0Xi¥??Cû(¼N7G?ü(IG?Ey ¡4ZÇ{ ?AJ?wr_9Ñ0`°??Ix_;î??O ? ?AO|â?^Iy$è_yE¿vùwyd$?x'ÜF&ÉyS?O?.Éàz>^»?½²PrQ6¥QOAMIoB?dd▌z?ä¼)?ò?ºàw▌AU$R?AaºP?ç à9??]eAc»P?hZ4??ä@AOèe?[A`mêA$?7i?$çMi(D¬W=°c?üOc½mxAOè+??ü(-?3E7wB#iÑYGJ?µ_¿;kSE~7O}«+p·<3+,_?A<rìE°?AC?;º"O?ò2XcúM p?ßïxpÆjÖ@ ?;`°_£zyçrAï4Öq«?W°y¬UÿE+"A«7py¬«·"ü@`?ò?û(æ ?Aq¬aX?? ?,ß▌!qâRC ?K`°.)?@`?_?\ü_D?ÿÄp.?@àsÖçE@ ?ì¬ìÉ?r?¬ozDá/I.-?^}_(▌àüÖ?_fO__C1(Udrè&cAEIM pQ74XUJ?!A`??R d? ?¥9@àdÖÉA-? _ A`}º%,7ë_ú«?{`°î¡3*HD?AJ$?T@`kXa@àKo ?@}V}?U?@2V2A? 0X ? K,y? o0Xo5V!0XÉ??!àÿE8?« d?@R?åNîWoX7Y▌`N?6«j_V-«÷?sbë3ªª ;1_ï#@ ?°Y_!? $½?5r`?@ ?F ê_IÄE ?$¬$BHN%A`??UÜ? ?u?IU? r`éL?AXxHIA¬?²H?:¬:ZªÖ`°Ö32v`°v@3.O?Aº¼?@ 7+·>²C ?1¬1\EE ?0XZîH?Aº£êjFàDI?;1?OC?*öRà?_'ï-íIí}F??ï▌±+Pp,ßaÑYÉ}Z?@àE?½r ?"L é¬EEO?0XD??0X?OU¼"A`éJ?A?WpHJ?AJ*?'"B?Aª¢:@`k-c@`3k32@  «??J@ 3+3:rC ?Q¬QdÅE ??,?? w$A`YQu5#p"ëDO?B ?4¬4RH???¬UwXn-T~sWàO7?ªº?ûO;3ç_µExou'÷«+(o?@ùOóGtLF ??$½?oq] ? K,y? C0XCñ? I0XI??0XU?Tl!A`m¡e,l&A`mFf A`d&A`eVG 0? ?5?¬ d? ?¥@à?¬;ªrfN$A`U ?? ??F? P? ?USWU!?A2K? ?APyÖôfîE[á▌?Oài?¡?Æ«y¥Xo<î'_^y?Çh+,ÉV0rù·?¼k"_nN`?¥,9+å#?AÖh▌ ?Aå0X??Pä&A`åÖG 0? ?5?« dK+ ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &«▌rªB ?e?A ?¡¬¡xG ?¬AH?*¬*Jª`°D26`°6#3`°?"2Hj°▌wDI?ownå7wîî?$«*O÷?öö>SUA~?(0É^±;?ªö?%cAU-? ?AU7÷5µ? '`°N?lHG?AJ'??"E?Aª¥j@`k'£@`'k'8O@àO¬KE'yò`°òk$C8? ?u<S@`B?AO pGÖUW3'`°N?m)HC?AJ#?D"I?Aªc«ª@`? ?¥C@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB ?«ö?[ó?ßÜxo-¢ª?îä~oIìùWmQ^½EYÉyêE>"P_ôü?@àcI_`}\ ?AK ?APÖP¼?#?@RVRa?@V%O? 0X[h? ?0X???? 0XDT?0X?O??"A`?"+.ü$A`i,#ë?ª«?0X'A!A`¥?BO$A`OOU °L?AO 0?@R?åNîCU?!xù3?Oè¢K,?ª_?éüö-ª ;1O$B!?ATYÜ_??(J é¬¢'?? 0XY??E0XE?U,%A`Å+$%A`%FT!A`UQ °? ?µ?? °? ?µ P? ?U@D% ?? ??Y1!?A(Ö(²â"?AO?F@ ?;`°î"º?8? ?u"lK!?@V)$?@MI?;1_½YE?½xÑu'÷?÷?cdêRVUD?Ü__?òG ?TYÜ??b2G é¬axB?AO 0? ?5_ ?? ??Ti!P? ?UEIu ?AÖZÆ"?AfÖfd& ?@V??@fVfuä? 0X£E?? ?0XîH?Aº£êjFàDÖ?°-? 0Xi50X5uU,`%?x`Moæ_¼nU(?öh¼U_?oÆa~òê?@?Ñx¬Q???la?ÿqKÉk°?úJA@àæ6Y??3R>ì A`í?f\? ?uy?@nVn}d? 0Xc,?? ¿`°'Ü? ?uGOO?A?¬a[O`°OH!j`°jêª*X&A`éJ?A?WpHJ?AJ*?'"B?Aª¢:@`k-c@`3k32@  «??J@ 3?kzGOIovçV~sWàî_H2±ª?}oiOjï3Uì??ì»O"ª`ßX?¬Y??? ¬!Pus_S» pëE?@ ?t¬t?Z¬ZzªÖ`°Öq2v`°v?3.M?Aº'|?G ?+¿F2D ?a0XÇ3&,í? w$A`YQu5#p"ëDO?B ?4¬4RH??¬?ºª?0X:?`°?â?`°?#-ªHj°jßa15OùI]?Wß"ª*èNîWïI?OUàO[O?Ü_r ü@à#åOIÑ1>&?ôÖÇu?,`°ô%A`Å+8$%A`%FT!A`UQR °? ?µ?? °? ?µ P? ?U@D% ?? ??Y1!?A(Ö(²â"?AO?F@ ?;`°î"º?8? ?u"lK!?@V)$?@MVM]U? E,? C$5Xîä>To???{)d?.±?;1? ú???A_`?pÑªº?û?M"\?@OIyzJE?¢?^A*J[ ?? ??Ey P? ?UTXe!?A"K? ?APÖP¼?#?@RVRa?@V%O? 0X[h? ?0X???? 0XDT?0X?O??"A`?"+.ü$A`i,#ë?ª«?0X'A!A`¥?O$?O`1?ûOU-üUK?mQwr¿"p?i;_.eUYÉyê?)o?@OIy#(&#?Aq?^A:r@?@ ?',m? C0XCñ? I0XI??0XU?Tl!A`m¡e,l&A`mFf A`d&A`eVG 0? ?5?¬ d? ?¥@à?¬;ªrfN$A`U ?? ??F? P? ?USWU!?A2K? ?APyÖôfîE[á▌?Oài?¡?Æ«y¥Xo<î'_^y?Çh+,ÉV0rù·?¼k"_nN`?¥,9+å#?AÖh▌ ?Aå0X??ä&A`åÖG 0? ?5?« dK+ ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &«▌rªB ?e?A ?¡¬¡xG ?¬AH?*¬*Jª`°D26`°6#3`°?"2Hj°▌wDI?ownå7wîî?$«*O÷?öö>SUA~?(0É^±;?ªö?%cAU-? ?AU7÷5µ? '`°N?lHG?AJ'??"E?Aª¥j@`k'£@`'k'8O@àO¬KE'yò`°òk$C8? ?u<S@`B?A pGÖUW3'`°N?m)HC?AJ#?D"I?Aªc«ª@`? ?¥C@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB ?«ö?[ó?ßÜxo-¢ª?îä~oIìùWmQ^½EYÉyêE>"P_ôü?@àcI_`}\? ?AK ?APÖP¼?#?@RVRa?@V%O? 0X[h? ?0X???? 0XDT?0X?O??"A`?"+.ü$A`i,#ë?ª«?0X'A!A`¥?BO$A`OOU °L?AO 0?@R?åNîCU?!xù3?Oè¢K,?ª_?éüö-ª ;1O$B!?TYÜ_??(J é¬¢'?? 0XY??E0XE?U,`°%A`Å+8$%A`%FT!A`UQR °? ?µ?? °? ?µ P? ?U@D% ?? ??Y1!?A(Ö(²â"?AO?F@ ?;`°î"º?8? ?u"lK!?@V)$?@MI?;1_½YE?½xÑu'÷?÷?cdêRVUD?Ü__?òG ?TYÜ??b2G`à¬?üá__>~üÉ?ÇÇ_9ù? ?$A`?+û?ûOko+Å`iC8? ?u>s+"p+£r`5koE/?_>~:°1ÇºA¬ò?»__?P??ÉhÑä½M_¼?£ÖSk«fo=z¬;¬·?g %P~sJOp?h_föï$?5ydÑ{I<V¬?ûóÿúßü?mûµ=_í¿ûo?öz{ïÆëñb?ï>N?íß_üûßaLGüÿ_ôO}L??EO1yYiz¿FJíÅ1÷ô¢?_E4òT-^iD▌'Pñz?1µ·ú¿(°?eOFÆÜo{'_¼gUOx?¢â?H_O^?à?j{AÅlY>·ëOS?Z"N/g?ÉT?x>k?_?S±f²Fí}?i>sªæôôA?ûIÖo}-_?3¥:??ºÅl»v=?ic?H OöxO9ôa½UOMñö¬¢E{]µi«teè:ê_?NgU9OU#O?ö^DèâN;1???M?A?µz?Çc°sèp▌ g?@ïùE°'Sºô½I£ºimb?Ü"OUáO???Oé¢Ä?àÜ?a}VÖ5? Ñ3=l<?5^/¿?DAö=ß?O?L?£ImU'±ßöí="Ç_O£/@oíLz·L3í?ô<;?|J&t?rë'á▌ü{cLA~lNë¢Oó?é]Ai?uqg]4U*â·?y?2í??zöx;O'wÅS){E?yë{BOr*J'Y_.vÑ_á=ùYOO?8?y_n&AèµI:¼K[O'?céY£v\11J?}n?X(~·N2X±öO+XñÖOcm5X].CßF;?~'Äà?«^o°ARôc wUOADoa=xß?-Ü????_Lï~h?cW?_ëíO7I?@8më?5å<Y3b-_UÅêO??x±?úº?ÆlG{lñ_éÄ[}z_«w|·O??QºF3- ?U▌;o?º?Æ?í-e?OOèsIyv Yº-1X½7zIqlG?Cä-9Liw{¥O}çñü?Wì#Q_]GY?pf°▌?û?3N;1çD???OO6Y3oÄ▌b-ä-A?æ3ÜI?}·íH;?~D÷y÷cAQzworë½Yo?Wzoäé?¡gO?IÉ~tD?O?}£¿O:ê_Vïö?s?UW?me-êé?4;"ùw1x¬_¥=±_AO|bÑc??b¡_<▌D_Y?öE½3göæï+N?Äi?d??}?ìKÇô_A=ZG=ëº^räÜ;gU`o4úAKÄ??O?B?ÖO?g?4U¥g«??bKé?gU?(0àô?SPS▌çî?5ó[A*?Y±ô¬Q;¥ràlßî??b¡oU?d1XS?Orú¿ÿçÇÿëÿá?_oOÿùx'íñ?_öG{±yú¿_ç?¿ûß¿_/Æ»íÅ>¬=ÿ?¿ÿo-¿ü/¿kObJ?U"Ä?xñ¿yx_Æ?ñ¼=?%U_íy¼ñaI?UBEäö?°í-öJ¬OU?IAE6n##·▌h?U?·ñ1yEE?(½åtQQ?¥?F{_ñnImuo£ºön_?ô%¢?x1Jî?ôlUë1=t-x?¬zJ1,-AF åq?L<)cX¬_?Å#OhOU??Od?)ÿd??ÿ["iA@Y!J?XûcU»QidOò?¥yqoü,ñ<Bµ;ÉX4b??O^?UZIñ¼y?ò£_x_G?o¿>o#U?úß_£U¢¢":drN_+O;$?h?[?_UïK)dó(¼=ZI?U?UIBG9}éE6??w]"PÄ??+Æñ¿?ö)dû+A-?? O_¼Ai¿ö~E±\OxÆóöh[??s{1V?çmJ?Æ°@U?ñVhG?è±èù?GæEÑ*1&?öA3?Ömµ·G?aQTO)?t21«½Oì?û!oÅI(¼·_{OU/?Ub1 *;Y?#ZD?Oz?qOD?["ß«?JUÜè¥>±Ai#?D:ú°åÖ°±oo?($?8=«è??>??c' Ä??F4IO;ti?C?_O')±?E'?üá÷2cz¬¢WU?_uüUçñk{ÉÇ?X"ì»zO,"B?MbE?¢¢~|Åá¿Fü"¢?i3B?(¡y:U¡7m4C¼5U1÷{=t?Ä▌?{>íILo3âl'CAàéE? ¡ºj¿?_3êè¥öè £?~ìwªqà'?Qaaë?ODU)?6?¥U[ñnLMU_½7"?é?rÑKA1=Id°ºÇ?OÄ-x?|£ì(µ?Iûé¿??ü¡bÜI_13?Yqº??!G¡Bx6¬o¿GDî-y¿NêsTs{?Ol£º(0??hy D?s?í4¢?¢?a ?¢Q9r?wa0?#!??Y$úc?ê½'z??-A?yùïEz1%?ºE*ê?4â,?d:ö(6▌Ça_4B?~|ö£¢mpI3?|Q] éGQî+?O~OÇÄ_?½Çz??väÖ?AX("GiígT,b#ëA¢Ah?O?EAG¡QÄéy?Kèüa-1dèzG[FüH&~íK?_÷&lA¢ucd?£rE3òï_zE?G3Åàö$ö,?,Oì6"ïÅFU½Æ6=DÅá0=▌bn,'.hßÜWt¡£ñ"TI9H«xÄ?I9ú1w]HFIG?ô??EYO1F¥mbo?8º?÷#¥ëGt,O±B_?iÄêA£Y-º%fµ'¡½?4íÆ?o?7:*zaI~nA)?qDtà9&F?1&f±tP?I{Ä¡3"lï¥%Äê/ÆêQf"ßa ë?ÜU+±·÷C▌ï¢?vEæ}?2g[Au?]O(Ñ?bax¢åÜs??t12V??ú1u«7ú1¬xïF½1¬óïvcL$Ü3?_£A?xC?_!VïAéæE?O^:A_¢?ChcZd_ñzO½H5?Gü?Ut`ûcïö_?'YñnLï? ÑCI_òO??E3?Aj1_Mkß¿_»V ?  ??AUû$ä2XI]yfú_å3Io?µüüû/?g}ÿ@'½<}_8_?~RUô/?L'Aí??oE9>c]<>9?o'"iO?F,yößcI?_cá1xú½«iüÉYäo_ÄS?O_?F?ÖO?O#O¿?d_«Uö^~OHñzOo!??on?▌ñJÇ?ÿU?g_5Xh?éEoªAU_?5mDX>▌U?1UxU»äU#½í?iäHlùOy<RbüOüg4Zæñ?zyù#º?L▌?g_Nzä?U_?4ëç(gå6²{ßèñZhåMfV]|Uez?-Dî_ßYßAmdÿZOD~m?s|I▌ono9¿:I6?ooí18Uxû6ò4O!?_?zºåN¬)dv°Ité9Iå?G÷BëiIIV-æIcMWÉo¬pWí?dOU4¬1X3'á^>¬4XO?,¬yf¡wqlx  IIDATúåvôÜ?)_öèWç3Wky-e?µÜ²3Mdúë[?o*«kI)ü1à?Oìë.¬éoÖO?V7ëüÇ?3?µcy¢A- ?¬WëI?¿µqy99ûµåD_9E`=?dö¼S_¬·ûOL?>_m?_0[(díB_?óm¿=¬·G÷t-5çÅU9~¥Aæ1÷mùE?ÉJ?U??_Sà[Ea<5XOå_¬Ç?Ucúô<û'3x?²fxYgº¿oTkV~?+XY]IÖ?ú7ua?Akêêc?ä¼)NlB?dpy?p?Fyh?yOa«?»Ç?å?A`MYO?µé0K2x?üIr_??7áJ8??EU?7áJ8??Ey?Oo÷¢úa·¿o°fîê&ëB}#UJ(ö*c?¢HKà¼;17UôööñßÆ÷r▌?;ü_rEoîL»¬L??+A¥FA'O¬L??+A¥6êÖ_·åh·¥y÷xtWr`¥í?!P?@ù3W%±O?A?2XI'Å=Ö?3kWñër`]±Wä?@%V%5O?@BÖSó'æE+a£H?b¬b?*?l?¬Oûï??K?W`C}k>Uì{K{R{?cª`ïdn="3?_ª`ßX?¬l} (F êæ^L&å p]Öuµ?9ì'A`ígg&¬ A`-??#A`??Tä"A`åOC pëIVAà¬UJ_pnM?Aºµü?G`<k<c+ ?@>V>Md?@)V)9? +0X+A? 0Xû,?? x&A`][?U#?? ??^""?A Ö "B"?Aï?¬UwXnoEoî¼ú6SUAwr¿zgöü«"__¢îä~uå? (z_?? d1?W°>rK @`? ?¥?@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB «??ê@ ?-¬-'?E ?I¬IEL@ ?¬"*?I¬IêEF`°F?~`°4Ü? ?uGOO?A?¬a[O`°OH!j`°jêª*X&A`éJ cAr'÷¡ª?¼üUK?'tÑ?%ÜÉ}O_Ät~û??VUD?Ül¡@àzªnîxSB%?ôVQUEB ?,¬,JE?¢¬¢A*0X?`°?â?`°?#-ª`°ª(cOB?AUBEXOL?AU?I(@?A* ¢EL?AE¬?Ü@`kYq@à'K# ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &?E?Ü__nåI^¼h?º?ûE?{LU1xu)«*èNîWïLù#?AGªnîA1?#?ôÖq??<!A`iJ?A?WpHJ?AJ*?'"B?Aª¢:@`k-c@`3k32@  «??J@ 3+3:rC ?Q¬QdÅE ??,?? w$A`YQu5#p"ëDO?B ?4¬4RH??¬?ºª?0X:?Ek°▌7s__7m?Oû4^í/Åzaq?yoES Åh<Ö"@[AM?qIÿ,¥ä5XC}¥ ps?,ÅIY)v`°v@3.O?Aº¼?@ 7+·>²C ?1¬1\EE ?0XZîH?Aº£êjFàDÖ?°-? 0Xi50X5uU,`%A`Å+8$%A`%FT!A`UQR °? ?µ?? °? ?µ P? ?U@D% ??@R?5½#jf|»s+¿1+pwo$?XUA_·''µ÷?ªöD?Iö?YiTU°o,IÖnALD Ö"º1_cY8? ?udK ?@:V:I$?@-V-=U? 0Xë8? ;0X;A?? ?&A`]Z>É#?? ??_#"?Añ¬a??? ?v@ ?;`°î"º?8? ?u"lK!?@V)$?@MVM]U? E,? C0XCñ? I0XI??$5Xµï°Ü?üærA«oUt'÷«wfI¿j?*dê-êNîWWP d?òç?è?? Hzëaº@ 0Xú?`°?â?`°?#-ª`°ª(cOB?AUBEXOL?AU?I(@?A* ¢EL?AE¬?Ü@`kYq@à'K# ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &«▌rªB ?e?A ?¡?,wrªúAE?½xB?XA?ÜGPyJLÇàW°,hUYÉyA&rG êæ~=%d?@QI_`¥-,EB?AE¢?<(J?A**¬²@`? ?¥A@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB «??ê@ ?-¬-'?E ?I¬IEL@ ?¬"*?I¬IêEF`°F?~`°4Ü? ?uGOO?A?¬a[O`°OH!jHj°ÜÉyêíV_ì¥A?";1_T,Ç'?W?²ª?îä~oI?|D êæ_?@à8I_`W  ?A?@ ?¡¬¡xG ?¬AH?*¬*Jª`°D26`°6#3`°?"2`°2«#7E?AEV\oI? pGÖUW3'`°N?m)HC?AJ#?D"I?Aªc«ª@`? ?¥C@`(?¼kz3÷å-pOFid'?D@aO_R¬7÷?W_<R?Æc?'Üd+xü?[J^?5OW? 7'°ÉRÜ??ò@`k4S@àò¬EK" r`°rë#;C?AAUTo? ?¥@à?¬;ªrfN$A`U ?? ??F? P? ?USWU!?A2K? ?APÖP¼?#?@RVRa?@V%O? 0X[h? ?0X???? 0XDT?$5XO;¢fÆ·;·ò?»w÷F??Uì{K{R{?cª`?@?d_O?FUûÆ?O`íID@`?ª?û?U?A 0X'@#A`¥?DO"A`OOS °? ?µ?? °? ?µ piÖ¥å?<ù0Xù5?!O?A:? 0!A`i,#ë?ª«?0X'A!A`¥?O$A`OOU °L?AO 0? ?5_ ?? ??Ti!P?@R?UûE-yEoî¼úQUAwr¿zgöü«"__¢îä~uå? (z_?? d1?W°>rK @`? ?¥?@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB «??ê@ ?-¬-'?E ?I¬IEL@ ?¬"*?I¬IêEF`°F?~`°4Ü? ?uGOO?A?¬a[O`°OH!j`°jêª*X&A`éJ cAr'÷¡ª?¼üUK?'tÑ?%ÜÉ}O_Ät~û??VUD?Ül¡@àzªnîxSB%?ôVQUEB ?,¬,JE?¢¬¢A*0X?`°?â?`°?#-ª`°ª(cOB?AUBEXOL?AU?I(@?A* ¢EL?AE¬?Ü@`kYq@à'K# ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &?E?Ü__nåI^¼h?º?ûE?{LU1xu)«*èNîWïLù#?AGªnîA1?#?ôÖq??<!A`iJ?A?WpHJ?AJ*?'"B?Aª¢:@`k-c@`3k32@  «??J@ 3+3:rC ?Q¬QdÅE ??,?? w$A`YQu5#p"ëDO?B ?4¬4RH??¬?ºª?0X:?Ek°▌7s__7m?Oû4^í/Åzaq?yoES Åh<Ö"@[AM?qIÿ,¥ä5XC}¥ ps?,ÅIY)v`°v@3.O?Aº¼?@ 7+·>²C ?1¬1\EE ?0XZîH?Aº£êjFàDÖ?°-? 0Xi50X5uU,`%A`Å+$%A`%FT!A`UQR °? ?µ? °? ?µ P? ?U@D% ??@R?5½#jf|»s+¿1+pwo$?XUA_·''µ÷?ªöD?Iö?YiTU°o,IÖnALD Ö"º1_cY8? ?udK ?@:V:I$?@-V-=U? 0Xë8? ;0X;A?? ?&A`]Z>É#?? ??_#"?Añ¬a??? ?v@ ?;`°î"º?8? ?u"lK!?@V)$?@MVM]U? E,? C0XCñ? I0XI??$5Xµï°Ü?üærA«oUt'÷«wfI¿j?*dê-êNîWWP d?òç?è?? Hzëaº@ 0Xú?`°?â?`°?#-ª`°ª(cOB?AUBEXOL?AU?I(@?A* ¢EL?AE¬?Ü@`kYq@à'K# ?A0XwT]?H?A:¥@ +?A &«▌rªB ?e?A ?¡?,wrªúAE?½xB?XA?ÜGPyJLÇàW°,hUYÉyA&rG êæ~=%d?@QI_`¥-,EB?AE¢?<(J?A**¬²@`? ?¥A@`(k(^A@ )+c0OB «??ê@ ?-¬-'?E ?I¬IEL@ ?¬"*?I¬IêEF`°F?~`°4Ü? ?uGOO?A?¬a[O`°OH!jHj°ÜÉyêíV_ì¥A?";1_T,Ç'?W?²ª?îä~oI??|D êæ_?@à8I_`W  ?A?@ ?¡¬¡xG ?¬AH?*¬*Jª`°D26`°6#;dBùI]??ôÉ?Pd?dY???`üb~_!K3X?`.F üUëbzH?r¬ïHZ~sWàwë,U)xEïD¢àw,·*?cù?HÖ▌.L2x?UIr_??6¡K2,¼?I8?K£¼?'É¼ê?q?O▌EÖ▌A,ÉàM"%ÉySÜ?+á`&eSJÜ?+á`&eSJÖ▌.L2x?HIr_??yq?ü?EMy|ÅA?AÇ`òc°|?&5X--@ @àº~üÉ?aÇG?¥ ? ?Ah°_É?HO`I!?"?ANv??à=º?oU1±îUa ?Ax,-?å_$?°?Aû?êç+±V?3??<=lE'«`9_EA0?ü?ê?k,ïE¿üòcyaALLG ?Mf/wµ??A¬?[µ?E·?ñ?"~,A«MySN?? °??íu%(A^oç_¥?_?°½x|?¡`ùAÖ>wo__O?öXhèIk~úçE¬oüOëi<ÆcñIçäE,?/__z{xu?oîùaZZ¬I??¢L_|d_ô?E½?YU`-»«A'¬·ÇOE~opOE`Ç*;µ_òtî?,D~ºYm+__?~?ôOMy¡Y£Sßöë?fåcaê1gA_½_??AúmIIC`IöúÖ$oSÅì?ñêo<å_.???ª°p.&_?Kb>ñ['¬$ôÖì _é?Ç6[ß{;RZîêW?É«?__Ü_c°¢??¬°>_\TAzk_?Ç`½EdA¬U^?ÖES~?OÉ%DY?ä[» I£"S¡x? khúöAA'¬<èÖì ëòOEo_?°▌÷>Oiê·Vroö/É?O(?oYW¬I/bMXyOjf¼▌WA_?Mc~?í!½¼Y^cOY8ì0XO)3çyN<;`??å?5?u&ô[!?yUù(ö-o-Ö[¼ûEU1ëí°#æa?OÖìOìï½_·;?r7L?AúñÖO?rWÖê?cb°9?Aòöúöüyè½ÖìAOÖ?µIç?|Å)'8ñ,ÿ->?ü(Ä+ïûö?yQù_b°vX?q}o-?µá-!?u_I -Äµf3?U»=fE`½1XëSÅ`-lhA²Hh°²!J?I«SO?Iz<£,_,ztl_IdcLAzÉ¬Ö[·ôT_å¿z£å¿?ÿ,yìù·a¬OV?_ôû^ë?m#o:??íuåÅ?W{IAô*òEOO_qå?·ê,¬Mvê?ò?o°²Qm°ö1«~LIö?p]SïoÖë¼roO/M-lo·?2XV?å}åÜViÑe?5YIÖ\/idÖüe1æK%E?xòö$yV?-w?U>¼dA2XCÖEMcYÖWI¼òOºåkWk?<VA`y?{O÷%÷@¿devW°ßï<?AEíuá?_öÉòö·?xÉ@ò/÷Ö]-±1oÖE?kI^???l°Öhw2r?;A?¬v»«?[Eo'²?·vûxV8?åÇ?ÿêuÆqá6kIÖ?ï]=U_-hß%°r{]_P6]/??_ç&<}W£éêkNZkIOoa¬ò4±EÉwæ+!??;AÖC`y?do=DOíeúâò%r5?I«¿IÖTñtI"¿n°fGEîa-ºIzåº?_`I_YU?Æ#du+·x·±µO7?_Ç?1~v)%áèëII?_?í?ê,çG_¬?æ1æò)ç?ò?`°ùzw-Üæ9ëOo(zU{Ox{>}YO{_²?.ºòpëÉ<%3D`-ñXE=½UKa@`?AUër2kA}å??Ao=VáÖWv?½??s39Æ`µ??_ßr>ñX¢L_?9÷Ä??y»=ÖU|?'?5BAá+?_Oµ#ê_î-)N?»:c?G,á?A:ªy▌q3XgnI#@??A=I.Y?yë?AU?@BW7X?_?):$¿&?ú?? 0?AO£Oñ;»$$A`?åE+X=¿O,yC ?I?n(Ö?}VL?`°4Ä`?HTL8?A£Aúåo,<NHÉ?d?·IÖ?A`?D?Aò??A ?ßIV3VEûIU?-pro¼ö-xß&<nAE»??0X#b?µ;ò«[»I_<y?á·"?3X_îeO rd"?²ZÆµ|¿«Waw·EaDëyn~ n¡HNà?«[«e?ojO·^ÿ¢ OIOOïå8â'y6æU_D·ré?7Æ|5ìíôòkVàôx·p▌=ú?éo;p?A[U3Oa?? KW°▌?Æ_1ûÄdqß?9åcda?UU«aßz}Ç?{O?8y,?A▌ï_=O?Oì8"ìi1?Uö4^[3½¼Az¼I÷ôºÑSaµ`°Öo½ózh0XN p¼AZï±ºi?î}_.b}EH-÷k>â<D"e°º]{z_Yscl6fúéIO?=?ö-y=Ä`IVù"?q>oÜ+OO?-?°Wo-ó|ú'E±-Ä`91"?A?µÆcoíl½?yêA_e¼Ö$sì?yê?Aò??M^??Z«5gA/U?MZ¬1µàAvLÿ"?<këE_hO]_ìHE?ArrE ?OÖEÿIpá3ÅJkOYüAA[_`½:?l5USc±òúAD3U??Nßá?^aYo,ê-÷QUcIÖóy?X?oO?O/¬_Aµ²A?¥I`91"?Ak+u#o,[½z«?AjÅ?üùàU?±f'å¿ow?3O`-??cIjGE;Ç`u,ß5 £ÖE¿.D~î??zµ¡O,'Wb°^?ç?º?ë|?µò¼oöoy?g_^j½Aº?Çb°YO·ôu?ñM{x¥4?6I"Ué,?åä? Ç¬-V?u²ÇZo°?IIiëBkåY|º'_¡?R_?ar`=-k%UWUxû3?ëaS÷Iî??+l°öíGoodaß;ùï½OW?í£±rÖO/▌ÄÜ·W?fg_W_vUôú««YO|_ë$V??1ÜddO_oK~;`SU;2Xu½í«e{'fúB72XN p6?Ç?î,Ö?y½?Ç?_òêsÆ_¼>oX}ká3?Çß?ibAaÄî3:1_ÅßY0'L|?óS_.O¬1OkÆ-v?AUO"?W?Diúê_è%ïÖU'°¡?|N`Uc-ü???/-A=I|«(ër$0;äyßWr[öG\??íoêîE?AU-Ik???E d? ?5bAI?AE¬IDÜ?ìv??I~It"D m6UJ?ª??åcÜ°_a?sUE,(L 6ÿ@ ?5W½ªGWô?êÖÆ ? ? l °aèI?¬x ?  ? ¼!  ? ?AAç ? ? ??  ?  p0??Aq ?  ?  ? ?AAÇ±"? ? 0 ?  ? 88Ç? ? A`!?  ? Lààp+ ? ? ??  ? p0??A ?  ?  ?  ?AAÇ±"?  ? ? ? 88Ç?  ? A`!?  ?Lààp ?  ? ?? ?  p,?ÿ\3ö?!    IENDrB`?
```

Please let me know what format is this string, so that I can convert to appropriate image format and save it to a file.

Comment: I am sure you asked this before.... However, i did a 10 second search for the usage of your oscilloscope,  https://forum.tek.com/viewtopic.php?t=137065&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=8221b11e52d51f1bd857eb852c6a148ce2c72190-1601266799-0-ATlam6bF87La_eNGkR8sEvI5rMAs_nVekhun41Z54eUHclec3ravlmLbGscRytkQjogotGOqj_1GwbXsfL8mkgNNYs9vriAzxt9_vMYDxl237K3i1C0HYTfixRGXlsRc1KZ3dQnDzAlNaByZOC7m0ffvaUM4-v_0AY61ER08asFkP3uAh-BqeXkTcACKvH4iV0eYDOp7VnS1M5-DOHvHZulA-tLJPo1cZhRNRJgFyRK08ZUE0vXKK374qJFr1ItOIpVxQgxrlzXgx_n9ORhVq8_yPYWaEBeGvUl2riL648pHbyWPRXBBJk2YeaOtqElqIunTlEy-trbVK18KsjBmE-uWvPr3_Di3BFrtOZ7EjWAx

Comment: @MichaelRandall, yes but that had few assumptions from my side, so I removed it.

Comment: Take a look at that example at the end, and if your problem persists i would suggest getting in contact with the manufacturer for the appropriate documentation, or using their forum. This is not a C# problem, its a research and documentation problem

Comment: It seems the example is using `Read_raw` not `Read` , i am not sure if this is going to fix your problem, though I doubt you are going to get much help here with this sort of question

Comment: @MichaelRandall, the example in the forum is for python, ok I will check with the oscilloscope documentation. Thanks

Comment: `status = scope.Read_raw(out ImgBuf);`  and `File.WriteAllBytes(fileSaveLocation + filename + ".png", ImgBuf);`

Comment: @MichaelRandall Read_raw is not available for C#, it is available only in python. So that is the issue I am facing.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095201/how-to-write-png-data-to-a-file-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment113342439_64095201). Your comment there was _" I never encoded some random text to binary data, and trying to decode it back to save it as image. I am getting the image data from hardware. I just don't know what format it is, and I am receiving it in a String data type of C#."_.

Comment: Responding to that comment: if you have a PNG file _as a `string`_, string encoding has been used to interpret that binary data. There is no other way you would have a PNG as a `string`. On that basis, it is not possible to restore it to binary data which equals that of the original PNG file. No can do. Sorry. [See my example from before](https://rextester.com/XIZDK48913). It seems likely that `Read` is doing the binary data->`string` part behind the scenes.

Comment: I'll say it one last time: if you have a PNG file as a `string`, _it is already corrupted_. No amount of code acrobatics is going to fix it. The problem is caused at the point where the PNG became a `string`.  If `Read_raw` doesn't exist then you'll have to contact the entity that maintains the library you are using for help.

Comment: @John, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @John That depends entirely on the way it was converted... if the operation just cast the byte values to Char then this is perfectly reversible, and if not, chances are you'll still be able to find which text encoding it used to convert it, and use that to convert it back. Sure, the version pasted here is hopelessly corrupted because a bunch of unprintable stuff was replaced by spaces and question marks, but the original data _may_ be fine. The shown data is most certainly _not_ ASCII, as you use in your example; it clearly contains accented characters, which indicates a full 8-bit data range.

Comment: @sattva_venu If you manage to convert the text back to bytes in a way that the first eight bytes match `{ 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }` you probably succeeded, since that's the standard start of a PNG header.

Comment: @Nyerguds Is your assertion that if I convert a random stream of bytes into a string, and then back with the same encoding, that I'll get the same result?

Comment: If it is done with an 8-bit text encoding, yes. You used a 7-bit encoding in your example, so all upper bits are lost. An encoding should be a 2-way matching of the entire data range. I'm guessing this one is just converted with Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Nyerguds Have you tested that? https://rextester.com/YGRMIC12356

Comment: @John That code is most likely just introducing byte order marks, and none of those are 8-bit encodings.

Comment: @Nyerguds So what is an 8-bit encoding that works for this?

Comment: Windows-1252 (`Encoding.get(1252)`) and ISO-8859-1 (`Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`) both work.

Comment: @Nyerguds Noted. I'll hold my hands up and say I was wrong then, although I stand by my comment that people should use an encoding actually intended for binary data.

Comment: @John Not disputing that, but reality is often a lot less elegant than one would like.

Comment: @Nyerguds That's unfortunately true :)